# R Subset rows by range of Time between several days

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset which I have to subset by a range of time and write the subsets into new dataframes. My problem is to subset the dataset between 12PM and 12PM the next day.

Small dummy subsetting by day.

```
dfrm  <- data.frame(a=rnorm(240),dtm=as.POSIXct("2007-03-27 05:00", tz="GMT")+3600*(1:240))
dfrm 

## Create list of dates in dfrm
date.start<-format(min(dfrm$dtm),"%Y-%m-%d")
date.end<-format(max(dfrm$dtm),"%Y-%m-%d")
datum<-seq(as.Date(date.start),as.Date(date.end),by="days")

## Get Date and Time from dfrm
dfrm$day<-as.POSIXlt(as.character(dfrm$dtm),format="%Y-%m-%d")
dfrm$clock<-as.POSIXlt(as.character(dfrm$dtm))
dfrm$clock<-format(dfrm$clock,format="%H:%M:%S")


## write dfrm daywise
j<-1

while (j<=length(datum))  
{
  name <- paste("day", datum[j], sep = "")
  assign(name,dfrm[which(dfrm$day==format(datum[j],"%Y-%m-%d")),])
  j<-j+1
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want `dfrm  <- data.frame(a=rnorm(240),dtm=as.POSIXct("2007-03-27 05:00")+3600*(1:240));split(dfrm, cut(dfrm$dtm, breaks = seq(as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(min(dfrm$dtm))-1, " 12:00:00")), as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(max(dfrm$dtm))+1, " 12:00:00")), by = "1 day")))` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to perform the solution inside the loop cause I have to do further steps inside the loop.

Comment: Was to slow in editing the first comment......Thanks for your reply. I need to perform the solution inside the loop cause I have to do further steps inside the loop. I used the sequence part of your example for "datum" so I can use them as breakpoints. Any way to perform the subsetting inside the loop? So to select all files between the datum[j] and datum [j+1] and write them to new dataframes?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe the answer helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
dfrm <- data.frame(a=rnorm(240),dtm=as.POSIXct("2007-03-27 05:00")+3600*(1:240));
lst <- split(dfrm, cut(dfrm$dtm, breaks = seq(as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(min(dfrm$dtm))-1, " 12:00:00")), as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(max(dfrm$dtm))+1, " 12:00:00")), by = "1 day")))
```

Now, take e.g. a subset of a few days:

```
lst2 <- lst[as.character(seq(as.POSIXct("2007-04-04 12:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2007-04-06 12:00:00"), "1 day"))]
```

And create a separate data frame for each day:

```
list2env(lst2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
head(`2007-04-04 12:00:00`)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.